# Why doesn't alignas compile when used in a static declaration with clang?

Tags: c++, static, clang, language-lawyer, alignas

I have a compilation error on clang and a warning with gcc with this code:

```
static alignas(16) int one_s = 1;                      // clang: error: an attribute list cannot appear here; gcc: warning: attribute ignored;
static __attribute__((aligned(16))) int zero_s = 0;    // on the other hand this works well on both compilers...
alignas(16) int one = 1;                               // this also works on both compilers
__attribute__((aligned(16))) int zero = 0;             // as well as this
```

Does anyone know why alignas is not accepted in the declaration that contains the static keyword? I used the --std=c++11 compiler option with both gcc and clang. (Edit: I used clang 3.4 and above  and gcc 4.8 and above)

Note that when compiling with Visual Studio (CL 19 RC) I don't get an error when using alignas in a static declaration like that.

Comment: Wrong syntax - it needs to be: `alignas(16) static int one_s = 1;`.

Comment: @Paul R I see that this compiles indeed, but VS accepts the other version too, even with /Wall. Is the syntax with alignas(16) before static the correct one (according to the standard)?

Comment: I'm not much of a language lawyer, otherwise I'd probably have expanded on the above comment and made it an answer, but if you take a pragmatic approach and Google for alignas you'll see that all the examples put `alignas` at the start of the variable definition. VS has always tended to be a little slack on standards adherence (which is why it tends to be a pain porting VS C++ code to other compilers), so it wouldn't surprise me it was slack in this regard too.

Comment: Here is the msvc bug: [MSVC accepts invalid program having `static alignas(16) int one_s = 1;`](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-accepts-invalid-program-having-stat/10581158)

Answer (score 1):

`static alignas(16) int one_s = 1;`   is **ill-formed** as per the grammar rules in [simple-declaration](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#nt:simple-declaration):

> ```
>  simple-declaration:
>    decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-listopt ;  <--------this is the case here
>    attribute-specifier-seq decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list ;
>    attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq ref-qualifieropt [ identifier-list ] initializer ;
> ```

Next we move onto [decl-specifier-seq](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#nt:decl-specifier-seq):

> ```
> decl-specifier-seq:
>    decl-specifier attribute-specifier-seqopt   //this doesn't match
>    decl-specifier decl-specifier-seq           //this doesn't match either
> ```

Now, neither of the above two rules allow `static alignas(16) int`.

---

##### Solution

The correct syntax would be:

```
alignas(16) static int one_s = 1;
```

This time, the grammar allows it.

> ```
> simple-declaration:
>    decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-listopt ;
>    attribute-specifier-seq decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list ; //this is used now
>    ^^^^^^^^alignas^^^^^^^^
> ```

Next we move onto:

> ```
>  decl-specifier-seq:
>    decl-specifier attribute-specifier-seqopt
>    decl-specifier decl-specifier-seq      <--------this is used here
>    ^^^^static^^^^
> ```

---

Here is the msvc bug:
[MSVC accepts invalid program having static alignas(16) int one_s = 1;](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-accepts-invalid-program-having-stat/10581158)

Comment: So tl;dr `alignas(...)` is essentially a form of `[[attribute]]`.